# GAE: Child object that is not in the class

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am trying to duplicate the pattern described in [Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html).  I am having trouble understanding how to tell GAE that Message index is a child of Message.  From [google](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Child_Objects_and_Relationships), they say that you create a child object by including it in the parent class, but this is exactly what we are trying to prevent.  So how do I store an entity as a child without including it in the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of entity groups, 'child' means the MessageIndex's **key** is a descendant of the Message's key.  It does not mean the MessageIndex list (or collection) is a property of the Message.

See the section titled "Creating Entities With Entity Groups" in documentation on transactions for an example of how to do this in Java.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html

Comment: In the python example he simply stores the message index immediately after he stores the message.  Will that make both entries part of the same entity group?

Comment: No.  The relationship must be defined explicitly.  The section in the link I provided above gives an example of how to define an entity group.

Comment: Specifically, you need to build the child objects key from the parent's key.